# Python 3.7+Numpy+pandas Arrays Selecting data between a range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-3.7

Ok I'm going to try to explain my problem, I have a csv file with data, the data is wavelength and amplitude, the image is include here.

[CSV data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fm1Y.png)

So, I want to select only data between 500nm and 800nm (wave),

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
excelfile=pd.read_csv('Files/660nm.csv');
excelfile.head();
wave = excelfile['Longitud'];
wave = np.array(wave);
X = excelfile['Amplitud'];
X = np.array(X);
wave = wave[(wave > 500) & (wave < 800)]
```

This does what I want in first instance, but I want to extend this selection to the column of amplitude (X), to have two arrays of the same dimensions. In my actual code I have to make an index to select the data in the amplitude array(X):

```
indices = np.arange(382,775,1)
X = np.take(X, indices)
```

But this is not the best practice, if I cant extend the first column selection to the the amplitude column I don't have to make another array to index the X array, and check the extension of the array, any idea about it ?
Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend [10 Minutes to `pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html), specifically everything up through the section on Boolean Indexing for this question. Reading data into a `DataFrame` and then splitting it into separate arrays defeats the entire purpose of `pandas`, as you're using it as nothing more than a glorified `csv` reader.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy it and paste it as text then format it as code. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2823755)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @ALollz pointed out, you shouldn't split the DataFrame up. Instead just filter the whole dataframe on wavelength. See the docs for [`DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some dummy data
excelfile = pd.DataFrame({'Longitud': np.random.random(100) * 1000,
                          'Amplitud': np.arange(100)})

wave = excelfile['Longitud']
excelfile_filtered = excelfile.loc[(wave > 500) & (wave < 800)]
X = excelfile_filtered ['Amplitud'].values  # yields an array
```

Comment: I get result with this lines
`excelfile=excelfile[(excelfile['Longitud'] > 500) & (excelfile['Longitud'] < 800)`

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)